# Can't upvote and can't access edit tray for answers on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have been facing this problem for quite a while. I have seen some similar question on Meta like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35075/cannot-vote-with-google-chrome) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39454/stackoverflow-ajax-problem-with-latest-chrome), but I don't think it's a problem of the Chrome version, because I can't even access these in Edge,Firefox, Opera & not even in eclipse internal browser :(.

Note that I can access the edit tray and can upvote on other sites like Meta, Ask Ubuntu, etc.

Please help me on this problem, because SO is one of the sites I can't live without :)

**Screenshots**:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Those screenshots don't help...

Comment: What steps have you attempted so far? I assume clearing the cache as is in Jon Skeet's answer on one of the questions you linked. Did you try disabling add-ons/extentions? What version of Chrome exactly are you running? _(It's still important even if you don't think it has to do with the version.)_ What version of Edge? Have you attempted this on a different network? (Work if you're at home (and SO isn't blocked) or home if you're at work?) Have you checked your console output? If so, does it show errors? What do they say?

Comment: Chrome version :Version 47.0.2526.106 m and Edge version:25.10586.
I had tried all the steps mentioned in answers of the questions above and not worked.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313869/somethings-broken-between-chrome-and-stackoverflow-com

Comment: @Kendra no output on console too :(

Comment: You say you tried all the steps in the above questions. So I can safely assume you've cleared the cache and disabled add-ons, correct? Consider editing into your question explicitly what you've tried, so your question is self-contained. I would also go ahead and edit your browser information, and that the console is showing you no errors. (Comments can be deleted at any moment, so it's best to have the important information in the question itself.)

Comment: @Kendra yup, you're correct I cleared the cache and disabled the add-ons and externsions.

Comment: Last suggestion I'm going to be able to offer for today: In the question I linked, the user describes a very similar problem, and it was solved by clearing the cookies. Have you tried that by chance?

Comment: @Kendra sadly yes

Comment: Check the "networking" or equivalent tab.

Answer (score 1):

**Update(Problem Fixed)**:

**1**)For *Chrome*, it worked after restarting chrome 3-4 times (after clearing cache &cookies) but not for edge.

**2**)For *Edge*, I simply cleared all data(from browsing to saved form data) and it worked after it .

If your problem is *still not fixed* then ,use a chrome extension called "**browsec**" or **other proxy** to fix this issue.

but I still don't know the ambiguous reason behind it and more or specific answers for it will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the issue had to do with cache.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing cache and restarting the browser does not get you around this problem, *and* you are connecting via a proxy server, it is likely that the proxy has a corrupted version of some JS file.

You will need to find a way to connect at least once not via the proxy server, then the controls will work again.